# Update a value if condition is met, without typing variable name twice

Tags: c++

I have the following code:

```cpp
int a = ...
//...
int maxValue = 100;
if (a > maxValue)
  a = maxValue;
```

Can this be done with a oneliner where I don't repeat the variable names?

One alternative would be

```cpp
a = std::min(a, maxValue);
```

but for reasons, I would like to avoid typing out the variable twice.

Answer (score 1):

Trying to squeeze stuff on as little lines as possible is a questionable motivation. However, if you write a

```
void assignMin(int& a,const int& min) {
    a = std::min(a,min);
}
```

Then the desired single line version is:

```
assignMin(a,maxValue);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could assign to a different identifier name first, then commit to `a`.

```
int temp = // blah
int a = std::min(temp, maxValue);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any built-in syntactic sugar in C++, but you certainly can roll your own.

In fact, std:::min and [std::clamp](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/clamp) are standard lib helpers that cover some aspect of the problem.

I would venture that it's not so much about avoiding typing a name twice, but about having to read two names twice, and then interpret the semantic meaning of the 2-liner! If you can come up with something that is semantically clearer to read, then go for it.

By example:

```
int foobarValue = ...
//...
int maxValue = 100;
if (foobarValue > maxValue)
  foobarValue = maxValue;
```

might utilize a helper such as

```
void use_a_semantically_appropriate_name(int& val, const int max) {
  if (val > max) {
    val = max;
  }
}
```

where `use_a_semantically_appropriate_name` could be

- `limit_to_max`
- `clamp_to_max` (although I'm not even sure whether you can "clamp" only to max)
- ... naming is hard :-)

I for one would much rather read:

```
clamp_to_max(foobarValue, maxValue)
```

than

```
if (foobarValue > maxValue)
  foobarValue = maxValue;
```